# OutOfMemory Exception while converting MemoryStream to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, out-of-memory, memorystream

I use the following code to return a byte array in `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   byte[] bytes = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
   ......
}
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    return ms.ToArray(); // This line throws OutOfMemory exception
  }
}
```

An `OutOfMemory` exception is thrown in the last `return ms.ToArray()` statement.

I need to set the resulting `byte[]` as `HttpResponseMessage.Content`.

Comment: How big *is* the stream? And why don't you write to the Response stream directly?

Comment: around 250MB...

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? The `File()` helper function accepts a stream parameter, so do others. 250MB is a *lot* to cache locally, only to copy to another stream

Comment: just try to instanciate a StreamReader with the reponse stream and then StreamReader.ReadToEnd(). This will give you the result string

Comment: @Radinator why do you think that allocating a 250MB string is going to have fewer memory issues that allocating any other 250MB object?

Comment: I use WebAPI.... i need to write the byte array from the HttpResponseMessage into a file. REceiving side code is: byte[] array = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result; 

File.WriteAllBytes(name, array);

Comment: Your last comment above and the last line in your question are conflicting. One states you want to **write** to an `HttpResponseMessage` (question) and your comment states you want to **read** from the `HttpResponseMessage` to a file. You need to clarify the question but either way you need to be working with streams and not read the entire byte array into memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That was not my intention. I just wanted to show how to reduce code. how to make his/her code more efficient. the code above takes at least 9 loc (effective code without curly braces), my code would take 4 to 5 loc (5 with converting string to byte[])

Comment: @user5663970 - if one of these answers worked for you, please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235))

Comment: guys....these are two different applications. there is a console application that makes and HttpRequest to the WebAPI. WebAPI sends an HttpResponseMessage whose content is the byte array. Console app reads from this and writes into a file.

Answer (score 2):

You should return the stream directly instead of reading it into memory first.

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateMessage(Stream input)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(input);
    return result;
}
```

Do not forget to set the appropriate headers etc.

---

#### Edit

> ... i need to write the byte array from the HttpResponseMessage into a file

Based on your last comment you changed your question and want to go the other way. Here is an example of writing to a file from a web response.

```
public void writetoFile(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var inStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("your file path here"))
    {
        inStream.CopyTo(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Igor posted the solution, and the correct way to deal with stream content. Use one of the MVC helper functions like [File(stream,contentype)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.IO.Stream,System.String%29) or classes like `StreamContent` to send the stream contents directly to the client, eg:

```
return File(myStream,myExcelContentTypeString);
```

or

```
return File(myStream,myExcelContentTypeString,"ReallyBigFile.xlsx");
```

The reason for the error, is that OOM can occur because memory is too fragmented to allocate a new object. A MemoryStream stores data in a buffer. When it exceeds the buffer limits, it allocates a new one with double the capacity and copies the old data. Copying 250MB of data like this is going to cause a *lot* of reallocations and thus a lot of memory fragmentation.

This can be avoided by specifying the desired capacity in the stream's constructor. This will allocate a large enough buffer immediatelly.

It's even better though to avoid caching this content though, by sending it to the browser directly.